# DebounceTimer not working: Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm making an api call on every key press. Following is the code:

```
getResponse(Event) {

  this.responseService.getHttpResponse(this.searchInstance).debounceTime(5000).subscribe(.......);
```

As far as I understand, this should not make an api call on every key press, rather wait for 5 seconds from the last key press and then get the results. One possibility might be, since I'm calling 'getHttpResponse' before debouncing the time (which is making an http call), therefore the http calls are being made regardless of the debounce time. But that should not fetch the results before 5 seconds. Please correct me if I'm doing something wrong with the approach.

Comment: @yurzui thanks for the help, but I'm not trying to cache the response, I'm trying to debounce the request call/response.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.responseService.getHttpResponse(this.searchInstance).debounceTime(5000).subscribe(.......);
```

This will not cancel new HTTP call if a keypress happen within less than 5s.

Instead it will :
 - fire an HTTP request
 - wait 5s before continue
 - if another request is made within those 5s, do not pass the response down the Observable chain

But what you want is :
 - wait 5s to make sure no more keystroke happen
 - THEN fire an HTTP request

For that please read that excellent article on [Thoughtram](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html).

***extracted from the article***
it might look something like that :

```
export class App {

  items: Observable<Array<string>>;
  term = new FormControl();

  constructor(private wikipediaService: WikipediaService) {
    this.items = this.term.valueChanges
                 .debounceTime(400)
                 .distinctUntilChanged()
                 .switchMap(term => this.wikipediaService.search(term));
  }
}
```